# Limit of $x^2(1 - x \sin \frac{1}{x})$ as $x \to \infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

Just like in title, I want to find such limit:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}
\left\{x^{2}\left[1 - x\sin\left(1 \over x\right)\right]\right\}
$$
I just want to avoid using Taylor and stronger tools. It should be done propably using l'Hospital and maybe some neat identities or tricks. I've tried l'Hospital, but it just produces mess. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Try $x=1/t$ and multiply through by $t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}{x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{x-\sin{x}}{x^3}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1-\cos{x}}{3x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}{3\cdot4\cdot\frac{x^2}{4}}=\frac{1}{6}.$$
Also, you can use $$\sin{x}=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+...$$ and we obtain $\frac{1}{6}$ immediately.

Comment: Or just keep on doing L'Hospital...patience...patience...:)

Comment: I added the solution without  L'Hospital. See now.

Comment: Thank you! First one using half-angle identity is very nice.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

with the help of the series Expansion for $x=\infty$ we get
$$\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{120x^2}+\frac{1}{5040x^4}+O\left(\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^5\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

We are dealing with limit $\dfrac{u-\sin u}{u^{3}}$ as $u\rightarrow 0$. But
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{u-\sin u}{u^{3}}&=\dfrac{1}{u^{3}}\int_{0}^{u}(1-\cos t)dt\\
&=\dfrac{1}{u^{3}}\int_{0}^{u}2\sin^{2}\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right)dt.
\end{align*}
Given $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, for small $t>0$, then 
\begin{align*}
(1-\epsilon)\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right)^{2}\leq\sin^{2}\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right)\leq(1+\epsilon)\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right)^{2},
\end{align*}
but
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{u^{3}}\int_{0}^{u}2\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right)^{2}dt=\dfrac{1}{6},
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{6}(1-\epsilon)\leq\dfrac{1}{u^{3}}\int_{0}^{u}2\sin^{2}\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right)dt\leq\dfrac{1}{6}(1+\epsilon),
\end{align*}
this shows 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{u^{3}}\int_{0}^{u}2\sin^{2}\left(\dfrac{t}{2}\right)dt\rightarrow\dfrac{1}{6},~~~~u\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}